# Adding License agreement to an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin for which i want to add a license agreement which user should accept before installing.

Could anyone guide me the steps to add the license agreement in the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to create a feature project of your plugin after that include that feature in an update site project. When you create a feature project, it has a tab called "Information", here you can specify a description, URL, License Information... etc..

Hope this helps.
-Abbas

Comment: Also, add a license.html to your plugins root (and don't forget to add it to the build.properties...)